# PyQt6/PySide6 ошибка пропущенного аргумента

Tags: python, pyqt, type-error

Хочу подключить всплывающее диалоговое окно для открытия с помощью кнопки из главного окна, сгенерированное с помощью UiDesigner

```
import sys

from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QWidget

from main_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from adding import Ui_Dialog as AddingDialog
from pay import Ui_Dialog as PayDialog
from transfer import Ui_Dialog as TransferDialog


class Bank(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window2):
        super(Bank, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.window2 = window2

        # рамка и прозрачный фон
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # self.center()

        # закрытие и сворачивание
        self.ui.nclose.clicked.connect(lambda: self.showMinimized())
        self.ui.close.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())

        self.ui.adding.clicked.connect(lambda: self.adding_balance())
        self.ui.pay.clicked.connect(lambda: self.pay())
        self.ui.transfer.clicked.connect(lambda: self.transfer())

    def adding_balance(self):
        self.window2 = QDialog()
        self.ui = AddingDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window2)
        self.window2.show()

    def pay(self):
        pass

    def transfer(self):
        pass


class AddingDialogClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AddingDialogClass, self).__init__()
        self.ui = AddingDialog
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window2 = AddingDialogClass()
    window = Bank(window2)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

При включении без этой строки:

```
self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

без проблем открывается главное окно и на кнопку открывается диалоговое окно, но при включении этой строки выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: Ui_Dialog.setupUi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Dialog'
```

Полазив в коде интерфейса, я нашел, что такое Dialog:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        if not Dialog.objectName():
            Dialog.setObjectName(u"Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(349, 239)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet(u"font-family: Montserrat;")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.frame = QFrame(Dialog)
        
        ...

                self.retranslateUi(Dialog)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"Dialog", None))
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"\u041f\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0447\u0435\u0442\u0430", None))
        self.close.setText("")
        self.lable_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"\u0412\u0432\u0435\u0434\u0438\u0442\u0435 \u0441\u0443\u043c\u043c\u0443:", None))
        self.adding_lineEdit.setInputMask("")
        self.adding_lineEdit.setText("")
        self.adding_button.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", u"\u041f\u043e\u043f\u043e\u043b\u043d\u0438\u0442\u044c", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

Это все упоминания о `Dialog` в коде интерфейса.
По сути это какой-то элемент из PyQt, имеющий размер styleSheet и другие свойства, но перебрав различные комбинации, интерпретатор ничего не принял и отказывается принимать эту строчку, но, как я понимаю, для того, чтобы отдельно задать свойства из `QtCore`, эта строчка необходима

Comment: n3vsk1y, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему. Опубликуйте модуль `main_ui.py` и модуль `adding.py`